# OpenLayers2 - Introduction tutorial problem

Tags: openlayers-2

I have just started looking into OpenLayers and I can't seem to even get the [example](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/introduction.html#putting-it-all-together) provided to work. I just get a blank screen.

Am I missing something really obvious? Here's the HTML I am trying to run.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>OpenLayers Example</title>
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%" id="map"></div>
    <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript">
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var wms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS( "OpenLayers WMS",
            "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'} );
        map.addLayer(wms);
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Using the code that you have posted, the map shows up as expected, without any issues.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the error console? In Firefox under `Extras -> Web-designer -> Error console`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it has something to do with the width/height of the container.
In fact, you must define the container's dimension to 100%.
But you must do it for the body but also for the html block.

```
<html style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <body style="height:100%; width:100%">
         <div id="map" style="height:100%;width:100%">
```

It works but it's not a good practice to add style directly in html :
[How adding CSS to HTML](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import)

Answer (score 0):

Download OpenLayers.js and just run it next to your html, and change the script source to just 'OpenLayers.js':

```
"script src="OpenLayers.js"/script"
```

That should work ( I removed the brackets to stop it from formating, BTW)

Comment: Hi, firstly thanks for assisting so quickly. I referencing the OpenLayers.js file locally as well (got the latest version). But still nothing is showing up, just a blank page. I think it's got to do something with the width/height of the container being set to 100%, I have changed it to 500px for both, and I at least get an image back now.

Comment: You can get code block formatting in gis.SE (or any stackexchange, I think) if you indent the text (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

The DIV height-width issue is probably browser dependent. Chrome, FF, IE10 should all be well behaved. This sounds like an issue I've seen in older browsers.